# benefit of deploy annaconda over docker or up on host

Tags: docker, anaconda

What is benefit of install annaconda over docker.
For python/pytorch programming. I installed annaconda docker image on Ubunut 20.4
But found many problems need to solve such as Display on **opencv2** (already solved). and **spyder** error on **libgl.so.1** cannot found and still no idea how to solve.

So, how about just install annacona on Ubuntu host. Becuase it should working as smoothly well on my job.

Comment: Why did you start using a container at all if it was not solving a problem for you? Containers are typically used for portability, but to learn more see for instance https://www.ibm.com/cloud/learn/containerization

Comment: Containers have difficulty accessing local files and the host system's hardware, including the display.  You must have root-equivalent permissions to run a container at all (this has improved recently).  The standard container model requires you to rebuild an image whenever you change code.  Local environments like Conda or standard Python virtual environments have none of these restrictions.